# In R ,dataframe ,how to combine variable content into a long character in easy way

Tags: r, dataframe

In R datafram, currently i using 'for ()' code to combine character in given variable as below.
Is there available function/more easier method for this ? Thanks!

```
ori_data <- data.frame(category=LETTERS[1:3])
total_character <- ''
for (i in 1:nrow(ori_data)){
  total_character <- paste0(total_character,ori_data$category[i])
}
```

Comment: Take a read of the `?paste` helpfile - I suspect you want `paste(ori_data$category, collapse="")`

Comment: @thelatemai  This is great  and i will referto the helpfile , Thanks!